# Reading a CSV File into a Linked List (Java)

Tags: java, csv, linked-list

So I am having trouble reading a CSV file and adding it to my linked list. I've read csv files into things such as arrays, arraylists, but never a single-linked list. Right now my issue is that I keep getting an ArrayOutOfBoundsException on the line of code where I parse salary. The code is part of my menu class in which I read the file and add it to the linked list. So my question is this, how do I read a csv file into a linked list properly? Thanks!

```
public class EmpMenu {

private SLList<Employee> list = new SLList<Employee>();

public EmpMenu() {

    Scanner inFile = null;

    try {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("employees.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException x) {
        System.err.print("File not found");
    }

    while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] records = line.split(",[ ]");
        String employeeID = records[0];
        String fName = records[1];
        String lName = records[2];
        Double salary = Double.parseDouble(records[3]);
        Employee employee = new Employee(employeeID, fName, lName, salary);
        list.add(employee);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with a `LinkedList`, but rather that `records[3]` doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to have nothing to do with `LinkedList` and the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` showed that the problem properly relate to split `line` to `records` string array, the `records[3]` doesn't exist. So check the length of the `records` and you will find what's wrong with it.

Comment: If this answer has helped to solve your question, you can click to accept this answer. It is helpful to other people that is encountering the same question.